# how to set the docker registry-mirrors in macOS 13.2

Tags: docker

I set the docker `Docker version 20.10.14, build a224086` registry-mirrors in `~/.docker/config.json` in macOS 13.2 like this:

```json
{
    "auths": {
    },
    "credHelpers": {
        "asia.gcr.io": "gcloud",
        "eu.gcr.io": "gcloud",
        "gcr.io": "gcloud",
        "marketplace.gcr.io": "gcloud",
        "staging-k8s.gcr.io": "gcloud",
        "us.gcr.io": "gcloud"
    },
    "credsStore": "desktop",
    "registry-mirrors": ["https://mirror.google.com"]
}
```

Then I restarted the docker and inspected docker info:

```
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
Labels:
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 hubproxy.docker.internal:5000
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

Seems that the docker isn't using the registry that I configured earlier, am I missing something?